# Need Remote_User / Auth_user in Flask Application with Apache 2.4

Tags: python, flask, apache2.4

I have a Flask Application and Apache 2.4 to serve API requests from Angular website. I need help to get windows username of whoever is visiting the website. I cannot show the login screen as my company has SSO authentication. Therefore, I need to find a way to get "REMOTE_USER"/"AUTH_USER" from the request headers or any other way.

I am getting None when I use
request.headers['REMOTE_USER'] and request.headers.get('X-Remote-User')

I hope someone can help me to understand how to achieve this.